# How to get list of all stored procs/functions/view which refer a table?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table table1 in database db1

How I can get list of all stored procs/functions/view which refer this table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%table1%'
```

[INFORMATION_SCHEMA.xxx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778%28SQL.90%29.aspx) are **not** reliable because the relevant columns are nvarchar(4000) which means you may not find the table. [sys.sql_modules.definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081%28SQL.90%29.aspx) is nvarchar(max)

Note the comment for [ROUTINES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188757%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

> Returns the first 4000 characters of
>   the definition text of the function or
>   stored procedure if the function or
>   stored procedure is not encrypted.
>   Otherwise, returns NULL.
>
> To ensure you obtain the complete
>   definition, query the
>   OBJECT_DEFINITION function or the
>   definition column in the
>   sys.sql_modules catalog view.

Comment: What about text field in syscomments

Comment: @Anish: same, nvarchar(4000) + legacy http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186293(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: Note that this will return a list of procedures that contain the *text* "table1", which might appear only as a comment. You then have to go through each and determine how that text string is actually used... but this still beats manually checking every stored procedure.

Comment: @Philip Kelley: yes, but even then it could still be relevant. of course, I'd hope one could use %.table1% because we always qualify with schema.... no?

Comment: Oh sure. The fun kicks in when you have objects (say, tables and columns) with the same name, or if you have overly common names (for instance, all our comment headers have "Author:" in them. Fortunately, we have no "Author" tables or columns.) Another reason not to name your primary surrogate key columns "Id" in every table...